# zsh: command not found: genhtml (Flutter + Code Coverage using Codemagic)

Tags: flutter, code-coverage

I'm new in DevOps, I want to create `code coverage` from unit testing `result` in `Flutter`.

And this is our command to run that:

```
flutter test --coverage && genhtml coverage/lcov.info --output=coverage
```

And this is the result:

```
00:03 +1: All tests passed!                                                                                                                                                                         
zsh: command not found: genhtml
```

Does somebody know how to fix it?

And also when I running this:

```
open coverage/index.html
```

This is the result:

```
The file /Users/rrifafauzikomara/Documents/speed-interviews-flutter/coverage/index.html does not exist.
```

Does somebody know how to fix it?

This is my [tutorial](https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-unit-testing-bloc-with-codemagic/) that I followed

Comment: it looks like `genhtml` is not present in your `PATH` ... could you try `echo $PATH` and check `/usr/bin/` is in it

Comment: `Last login: Thu May 21 21:14:45 on ttys001
rrifafauzikomara@rs-macbook-pro ~ % echo $PATH
/Users/rrifafauzikomara/Documents/flutter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
rrifafauzikomara@rs-macbook-pro ~ % ` This is the result of `echi $PATH`

Comment: the output of `which genhtml`?

Comment: the output of `echo $PATH` in my terminal

Answer (score 0):

You need to install "lcov" to access genhtml command.

On windows:

```
sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install lcov
```

On macOS:

```
brew install lcov
```

You can get commands for more platforms here:
https://command-not-found.com/genhtml